# Pre-images proving question

Tags: functions

Let $f : X → Y$ be a map. For any subset $C ⊆ Y$ (of the codomain of $f$ ), the
preimage of $C$ under $f$ or the $f$ -preimage of $C$ is defined as the subset (of the domain of $f$ ) $f^{−1}(C) := \{x∈X : f(x)∈C\} ⊆ X$.
When $C$ is a singleton $\{y\}$ , we also write
$f^{−1}(y)$ instead of $f^{−1}( \{y\} )$.

1. Let $f:X→Y$ be a map. (a) Show that for any subset $C ⊆ Y$ , one has
   $f^{−1}(Y/C) = X/f^{−1}(C)$.

Guys sorry I've no clue on how to start this question of proving. It looks obvious enough haha.

Answer (score 2):

The following statements are equivalent:

- $x\in f^{-1}\left(Y-C\right)$
- $f\left(x\right)\in Y-C$
- $f\left(x\right)\notin C$
- $x\notin f^{-1}\left(C\right)$
- $x\in X-f^{-1}\left(C\right)$

From the equivalence of the first and the last it follows that:
$$f^{-1}\left(Y-C\right)=X-f^{-1}\left(C\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

since $ f^{-1}(Y/C)= f^{-1}(Y)/f^{-1}(C) = X/f^{-1}(C) $.